# Assembly not found after setting AssemblyName in msbuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

If I set `AssemblyName` in MSBuild (`/p:AssemblyName="ApplicationName"`), I get the error that some assemblies are not found. If I don't specify the assembly name, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Please edit this question to have a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Try removing the quotes

Comment: Is this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4696) the same problem?

Comment: @SimplyGed thanks for the link. Do you know how to use `TreatAsLocalProperty ` in CLI?

Comment: @BendEg I'm afraid I don't. Sorry :-(